# Does AWS Lambda allows to upload binaries separately to avoid re-upload

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, continuous-deployment

I am new to AWS Lambda, I have phantomjs application to run there.
There is a python script of 5 kb and phantomjs binary which makes the whole uploadable zip to 32MB.
And I have to upload this bunch all the time. Is there any way of pushing phantomjs binary to AWS lambda /bin folder separately ?

Comment: No, they don't support that.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no way to accomplish this. Your Lambda function is always provisioned as a whole from the latest zipped package you provide (or S3 bucket/key if you choose that method).

Comment: Is there a credible proof of that ? Any links ?

Comment: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/running-executables-in-aws-lambda/ and https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/container-reuse-in-lambda/ are good places to start. The latter one on container reuse explains the lifecycle of Lambda functions, which should give you a better idea of why you must deploy a new binary each time.